# Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist (SpringBoot + RedShift )

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-redshift, persistence

I am trying to build connection with Redshift Database in my Spring Boot application. I have below entries in my properties file.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:redshift://redshift_url/db_name
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =  org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class =org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

In pom.xml I have below entries.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
  <artifactId>redshift-jdbc41</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
</dependency>
```

I have created an POJO file like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_data_table")
public class SomeDataTable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
private Date createdAt;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="date",nullable = false)
private Date date;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
private Date updatedAt;

@Column(name = "data_source", nullable = false)
private String dataSource;

 Getters and Setters...
}
```

But whenever I am starting the application I am getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.doMoveToNextClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Kindly guide me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Like @aleksandar mentioned, table information_schema.sequences does not exist in Redshift.

To skip information_schema.sequences, create custom dialect that overwrites existing PostgreSqlDialect

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect;

public class MyDialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {

    @Override
    public String getQuerySequencesString() {
        // Takes care of ERROR: relation “information_schema.sequences” does not exist
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then set `hibernate.dialect`to this custom dialect class

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =  <path to myDialect class>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `GenerationType.TABLE` for your Redshift DWH since it will query the `information_schema.sequences` table based on the `PostgreSQL9Dialect` which are not supported by AWS Redshift due to the missing support of sequences. As you can see the first query executed when using the `GenerationType.TABLE` will be:

```
SELECT tbl.next_val
FROM hibernate_sequences tbl
...
```

You can either try to the use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` [see Redshift CREATE TABLE doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html) instead for your id (see below) or simply don't use GeneratedValues since Redshift will not enforce the Primary Key...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
```

Answer (score -3):

As the error points out, the table information_schema.sequences does not exist in Redshift. Although Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, it has a lot of differences (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)

However, Redshift is specifically designed as an analytical database, optimised for running SELECT statements on large amounts of data, it doesn't like many writes/updates which makes it unsuitable for a Spring Boot app. I suggest that you choose another database type for your app, if you use AWS you can use for e.g. [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/)

Comment: I do not have option to change database.